# while query to Riak timeseries databse i am getting SQL Parser error

Tags: riak

I am getting this as a problem:

> {0,riak_ql_parser,                   <<"Used group as a measure of time in 712903232group. Only s, m, h and d are allowed.

My Query:

```
select memberId,COUNT(memberId) from Emp18 where start>1478925732000 and start< 1478925939000 and end>1478913322000 and memberId<712903232 group by memberId;
```

but I am getting response with following query:

```
select memberId,COUNT(memberId) from Emp18 where start>1478925732000 and start< 1478925939000 and end>1478913322000 and memberId<712903232;
```

and I am getting output as :

```
+---------+-----+---------------+
|memberId |steps|COUNT(memberId)|
+---------+-----+---------------+
|712903230| 350 |       4       |
+---------+-----+---------------+
```

Comment: i am using riak time series,,,,,,join is also not working , if any idea about this then mail me shahzad@canbrand.in

Comment: Hi Shahzad, Riak TS doesn't have joins so using join isn't going to work. I would also note that one of the points of StackOverflow is to share knowledge so emailing you the answer to your questions would be counter to the spirit of Stack.

Comment: Shahzad, as a follow up, can you please post your table schema? I attempted to recreate using the following schema:

CREATE TABLE Emp18 
(
 memberid   SINT64  NOT NULL,
 start    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 end     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 steps    SINT64,
 PRIMARY KEY (
  ( QUANTUM(start, 300, 'd') ),
   start, memberid
 )  
);

I didn't get an error when running the query with GROUP BY.

Comment: i am still not getting output by using either order by or group by.......need explanation,,,,,,

Comment: by using order by my query is :  select memberId,type,model,imei,deviceId,manufacturer,os,version,time from devicedetail where memberId=107 order by time desc  limit 1;   And My Table is like:-   CREATE TABLE devicedetail (memberId SINT64 NOT NULL, type VARCHAR NOT NULL,model VARCHAR NOT NULL,imei VARCHAR NOT NULL,deviceId VARCHAR NOT NULL,manufacturer VARCHAR NOT NULL,os VARCHAR NOT NULL,version VARCHAR NOT NULL,time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY ((memberId),memberId));

Comment: Hi Shahzad, in your new query above you have added SQL sytax that is not supported by Riak TS: ORDER BY and LIMIT.

I think you need to carefully review the documents at http://docs.basho.com/riak/ts/ to understand what Riak TS's current features and capabilities are.